# Number of syllables. Nuclear vs Linear. Is there a difference

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, syllables

I just looked up the syllable description of the words [linear](https://www.howmanysyllables.com/words/linear) and [nuclear](https://www.howmanysyllables.com/words/nuclear). On that website, it says linear has 3 syllables and nuclear 2. This is despite the 'ear' of both words being pronounced the same (and the stresses being the same, for instance, I checked in the CMU dictionary).

Is there a reason for this? Is the website wrong?

In general I feel I don't know how to split words in syllables when they contain 'ear'. For instance for linear and nuclear I wouldn't know what to say (although I would have bet both had 3 syllables). On the other hand in words like 'rearrange' it is pretty clear (*clear*, another of our friends) that the e and the a should belong to different syllables.

Comment: The website is wrong

Comment: Even Jimmy Carter pronounced "nuclear" as three syllables.  (As to 45, I can't say.)

Comment: _Nuclear_ is at least 2½ syllables, depending on how _clear_ gets pronounced; but the final /r/ is normally syllabic even when going for a monosyllabic _clear_. **Which** 3 syllables of _nuclear_ get pronounced is another matter. I've never heard _linear_ pronounced with fewer than 3 syllables, though.

Comment: Ok, thank you, so the website was wrong after all

Comment: The page you linked to seems to disagree with itself, in that it says *nuclear* has two syllables (which is wrong) and then in the section for rhyming words it says *mononuclear* has five syllables - unless they're saying an extra syllable mysteriously appears when the *mono* prefix is added.

Comment: @Hotlinks even GWB pronounced nuclear with 3 syllables, albeit in the wrong order and one of them incorrect :)

Comment: @Damila That sounds somewhat unclear. Or not.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth A U.S. president with those initials pronounced it "nu-ku-lar". The wrong order was that he brought one of the syllables from after the l to before the l, and pronounced it as a u instead of an e.  I was just adding to Hot Licks example that even when nuclear is pronounced famously incorrectly, it has 3 syllables.

Comment: @Damila I know (we get the odd bit of news from the States). I was just throwing 'unclear' into the melting pot. Con-fusion.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I totally* missed the pun with unclear. (*Added intentionally.)

Comment: See [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/543344/365490) for syllables.

Comment: That's a very interesting answer (and phenomenon). But what is the relationship with my question? At least in rhotic accents it's clear that the point of greatest sonority after the first syllable of linear or nuclear is the /ɪ/ (and in non rhotic ones both /ɪ/ and /ə/could be candidates. So the phonotactic rule of your answer allows both pronunciations with two and three syllables and can't predict which one it's happening. As I have known later. The fact that there are 3 syllables there, at least in general American is because the accent doesn't have the diphthong /ɪɚ/ anywhere

Answer (score 0):

"Linear" is the right template—3 syllables.
That said, saying "new-clear" is far better that saying "noo-kuler".

Comment: Nuclear - ˈ/njuːklɪə/ Doesn't it have two syllables, the second syllable composed of a diphthong? I seriously have this doubt.